# When comparing arrays why is "in1d" so much slower than "a==b"

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I need to be able to compare two images and extract any unique pixels to create a third image. To accomplish this I did the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("old.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("new.jpg")

image2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)

for (x,y,z), value in np.ndenumerate(img):
    dif = img[x,y,0] == img2[x,y,0] #only checking one color for speed
    diff = str(dif)
    if "True" in diff:
        image2[x,y,3] = 0
cv2.imwrite("result.png", image2)
```

This worked fairly well but the it took around 10 seconds for a 640 x 480 picture and I was hoping to get it closer to about half that time. So I changed this line:

```
dif = img[x,y,0] == img2[x,y,0]
```

to

```
dif = np.in1d(img[x,y,0], img2[x,y,0])
```

The results are identical but instead of speeding things up it now takes about 3 minutes. I'm at a complete loss as to why.

I realize that iterating over elements in large arrays is going to be time consuming in python but why is in1d so much slower?

(As a side note I would just use the "[palette method](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/fast-array-manipulation-in-numpy.html)" but I couldn't see a way to implement it for this purpose due to my limited knowledge of numpy arrays.)

Comment: Now, I am wandering why you are looping? why don't you do something like: `image2[:,:,3] = np.where(img[:,:,0]==img2[:,:,0], 0, image2[:,:,3])`. I believe your problem is coming from there. It will take a fraction of second instead of 10 seconds.

Comment: I really need to read the scipy docs more. You weren't exaggerating when you said a fraction of a second. This is incredible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.in1d` checks each element of its first argument against each element of its second element in the worse case. For each element `i,j` in `img` it checks if there is an element `k,l` in `img2` with the same value. Meaning that for your `640x480` image you can end up doing `(640x480)^2` comparisons.

On the other hand, `==` checks only elementwise, it checks if element `i,j` of `img` is equals to element `i,j` of `img2`. It will always has `640x480` comparisons.

`np.in1d` will work if you have images of different sizes, `==` will work only for images of the same size.

Comment: Really didn't think the answer would be that straight forward. Thank you.

Comment: I am happy to help. I just put another comment that you should look at. I think the problem is the loop. Check that out and let me know.

Comment: That is actually not true. The source code of `in1d` is pure python and relatively easy to follow, see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.10.x/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L305). The algorithm in numpy uses sorting, and while it is not optimal (but probably the best possible in pure Python), if your two arrays have sizes `m` and `n`, `in1d` has complexity `O((n+m)*log(n+m))`, which is far better than quadratic performance.

Comment: @Jaime, I agree with you for the complexity, I went for the worse case with no sorting! But you might also agree with me that it is still the source of the problem. Let come back to the present case where `n=m`. The operation `in1d` will take O(2nlog(2n)) while the `==` will be exactly `n`, without accounting for the overhead of function calls. So I will discourage someone from using `in1d` to do the job of `==`.